# Magento 2: Overwritten billing address?

Tags: magento2, checkout

I add custom billing address below shipping address in checkout. Before I choose the payment method I have filled in 2 different shipping and billing information. But one thing is that after I refresh the page, billing data is lost and it takes billing data. So who has a good solution to help me?

```
Before:
```

[image]

```
After refresh page:
```

[image]
[image]